# Wrong default behaviour in tkz-tab

Tags: tkz-tab

The following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{arrow style/.style   = {>->, line width=1pt}}
    \tkzTabColors[backgroundcolor=yellow!20]
    \tkzTabInit[color, colorT = yellow!20, colorC = lightgray!20!, colorL = gray!40, 
      colorV = lightgray!20,espcl=3]{$x$ /1,$f'(x)$ /1,$f(x)$ /2}
      {$-\infty$ , $-2$ ,$2$, $+\infty$}%
    \tkzTabLine {,- , d,h , d,+ , }
    \tkzTabVar{+/ $+\infty$, -H/ $0$ /, -/$0$ ,+/ $+\infty$ /}%
    \end{tikzpicture}
            
\end{document}
```

produces the following

[image]

I think the default behaviour of H here is wrong. As you can clearly see from the image at the third row of the table under -2 the line is drawn whereas at 2 is not. Altough I can fill the gap ( writing some more code ) I don't think that H should work this way.

Is there any way I can draw the second line under 2 in the 3rd row without overlapping zero using native commands from tkz-tab ?

**P.S:** While I can think of another way of producing the same table , I'd like to see a way using the commands from the tkz-tab package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, everything is OK with you table. It's meant to be drawn this way. Nevertheless, if you want to draw a line at the end of the forbidden zone, you can do it manually, like I did in the example below.

[image: tkz-tab draw inside]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[double distance=2pt]
        \tikzset{arrow style/.style   = {>->, line width=1pt}}
        \tkzTabColors[backgroundcolor=yellow!20]
        \tkzTabInit[color, colorT = yellow!20, colorC = lightgray!20!, colorL = gray!40, 
          colorV = lightgray!20,espcl=3]{$x$ /1,$f'(x)$ /1,$f(x)$ /2}
          {$-\infty$ , $-2$ ,$2$, $+\infty$}%
          
        \draw (N32) -- (N33); <----------------- HERE!
        
        \tkzTabLine {,- , d,h , d,+ , }
        \tkzTabVar{+/ $+\infty$, -H/ $0$ /, -/$0$ ,+/ $+\infty$ /}%
    \end{tikzpicture}
            
\end{document}
```

You sure know that, by writing `help` into the `\tkzTabInit`, you have acces to the nodes names. Then you just have to write the usefull `draw` command between the nodes where the line is missing.